# Data.table column generated with function taking multiple, cumulative and lagged arguments

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr, lag, rollapply

I'm trying to add a column to a data.table, where that column of the data.table is populated by passing the cumulative (lag 1) vector of values per group as well as a group-level attribute to a function, and then returning the appropriate value.

I have 8M rows, one per agent-day. My function is more complicated that myfun, but the key thing is that it takes two arguments from the agent-day table: a vector (Vector) of values for a particular agent from all days prior to the particular day, and a vector of agent-level attributes (PerAgent) that are all the same per agent.

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

DT <- data.table(Agent=LETTERS[1:3],day=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), PerAgent=c(.2,.4,.6),Vector=1:9,Answer=c(NA,NA,NA,.2,.8,1.8,1,2.8,5.4))

myFun = function(Vector,PerAgent){
PerAgent=PerAgent[1]
Answer=PerAgent*sum(Vector)
return(Answer)
}
```

The "Answer" column is what I'm trying to generate (obviously not manually as I've done here).

What I have right now that doesn't work because I'm trying to pass the second argument is:

```
DT[,Answer:=lag(rollapplyr(Vector,PerAgent,seq_along(Vector),myFun),1),by=.(Agent)]
```

If I didn't need to pass the second argument to the (simplified) function, this works:

```
myFun = function(Vector){
Answer=.1*sum(Vector)
return(Answer)
}

DT[,Answer:=lag(rollapplyr(Vector,seq_along(Vector),myFun),1),by=.(Agent)]
```

Your help is VERY appreciated.

Comment: Two solutions:
1. Pass `list(Vector, PerAgent)` as one argument instead of 2
2. Like many apply functions, `rollapply` and `rollappyr` allowing passing extra FUN argument though `...`, thus

`DT[, 
    Answer:=lag(rollapplyr(Vector, seq_along(Vector), myFun, PerAgent = PerAgent),1),
    by=.(Agent)]`

Comment: @Eric Number 2 worked like a charm -- thank you! One question about solution 1 though: when I try to pass list(Vector,PerAgent) it seems like data.table interprets this as the entire columns of Vector, PerAgent (not the individual elements). Am I missing something?

Comment: It does not work because `rollapply` internally change its argument to a zoo object, no really the problem of data.table. I don't know much about zoo, but you could try `myFun2 = function(x) {x=as.list(x); sum(x[[1]])*x[[2][1]}` as `x` is transformed to zoo before passed to `myFun2`.  Also, use `data.frame(Vector, PerAgent)` instead, as zoo does not accept list.  Anyway, this is an ugly solution that should be avoided.